# Normality of Sylow $p$-subgroup if all maximal subgroups have prime index

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is exercise 1.C.7 in Isaacs, *Finite Group Theory*. I have a solution, but I am suspicious that there is something wrong with it, because I do not fully use one of the hypotheses.

> Let $G$ be a finite group in which every maximal subgroup has prime index, and let $p$ be the largest prime divisor of $|G|$. Show that a Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal. Hint: Otherwise, let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $N_G(P)$, where $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Compare $n_P(M)$ and $n_P(G)$.

I argue as suggested in the hint. Suppose that $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $P$ is not normal. Then $N_G(P)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, so it is contained in some maximal subgroup $M$. This gives us the containments $P \leq N_G(P) \leq M < G$. Note also that $P \in Syl_p(M)$.

Since $|G:M|$ is prime and is not equal to $p$ (otherwise $|G:P|$ would be divisible by $p$), we have $|G:M| = q < p$ for some prime $q$.

Now $n_p(G) = |G:N_G(P)|$ and $n_p(M) = |M:N_M(P)|$. But $N_M(P) = N_G(P) \cap M = N_G(P)$ since $N_G(P) \leq M$. Therefore, $n_p(M) = |M:N_G(P)|$.

Summarizing, we have $n_p(G) = |G:N_G(P)| = |G:M|\,|M:N_G(P)| = q\,n_p(M)$. Taking this equation mod $p$ gives us $1 \equiv q$ mod $p$, since by Sylow's theorem both $n_p(G)$ and $n_p(M)$ are congruent to $1$ mod $p$. But $1 < q < p$, so we have a contradiction, and therefore $P$ must be normal after all.

---

My concern is that I don't seem to require that $q$ is prime, only that it is any integer satisfying $1 < q < p$. So, it would seem that the hypothesis "every maximal subgroup has prime index" could be replaced with "every maximal subgroup has index no larger than $p$". But Isaacs is generally very economical with his hypotheses, so I suspect that there is a problem with my proof. Also, this answer seems much more brief/straightforward than usual for this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If $P$ is not normal*, then the contradiction you obtained is correct.

Note that he says $p$ is *largest* prime divisor of $|G|$, and this  with his another hypothesis *implies* that *all maximal subgroups have index $\leq p$*. Your remark on hypothesis is correct, and so far, I didn't find any example where your weaker hypothesis fails the theorem.

Comment: OK, thanks. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something subtle.

Comment: All the arguments run *around* $P$, so even weaker hypothesis can be done- *all maximal subgroups containing $P$ have index $\leq p$* But, possibly, he may have written a hypothesis which do not trouble too to the beginners. He is a *best teacher* as well (I heard), so for that, he may have tried to write in simple form. This is only my feeling. Anyway. Thanks to you also for posting nice questions, revising our vocabulary.

Comment: Good point, the only maximal subgroup we need is one containing $P$. He is a very good teacher indeed. I read a large part of his *Algebra* a while back and I really like his style. I will try to get as far as I can in *Finite Group Theory*, although I hear it gets harder as the book progresses. You will see more questions from me, no doubt. :-)